# Refreshing toolkit:listpicker after database update

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, wptoolkit

I have toolkit:listpicker in my windows phone 8.1 app mainpage.xaml

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ListPicker"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    Margin="40,10,0,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Grid.Row="1">
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <toolkit:ListPickerItem Content="{Binding ListName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
 </toolkit:ListPicker>
```

and another page that add's item in local database. 
When i add item, listpicker is not refreshed until i close app and reopen it again.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the Inotifypropertychanged pattern on your datasource. That way the UI wil respond to any changes you make in your datasource.

http://danrigby.com/2012/03/01/inotifypropertychanged-the-net-4-5-way

Comment: I already have that in both model and viewmodel classes and it's not updating.

Comment: are you sure that the datasource is updated and that inotify works properly.